# zImage loadaddr in Uboot

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

How do I decide starting address/load address for zImage in U-boot for beaglebone black?

Different article shows different addresses. I went through technical reference for AM335 but could not find any information.

Answer (score 5):

So, the answer is that to a certain degree, it does not matter.  The *zImage* file is designed to run from an arbitrary location.  The most important constraints on where to load things to are best described in the [Booting](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/arm/Booting) file in the Linux Kernel.  A modern U-Boot, for TI platforms such as the Beaglebone Black will have a default environment that uses addresses based on that document.  Looking at the [code](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/u-boot/latest/source/include/configs/ti_armv7_common.h#L33) in U-Boot we see that the *zImage* is loaded to 0x82000000 and the device tree to 0x88000000.

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful.